# Update variable fields of document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, updates

I have the document:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eaa5fd865ee7ee63dafb93b"),
        "RId" : 501,
        "details" : [
                {
                        "code" : "code1",
                        "list" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "first",
                                        "ip" : [
                                                "1.1.1.1",
                                                "2.2.2.2",
                                                "128.2.1.2",
                                                "127.2.1.2",
                                                "128.2.1.4"
                                        ]
                                },
                                {
                                        "ip" : [ ],
                                        "name" : "second"
                                }
                        ],
                        "currentFeed" : "test1",
                        "hostName" : "xyz",
                        "password" : "yyz",
                        "ip" : "3.132.76.51"
                },
                {
                        "code" : "code2",
                        "list" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "third",
                                        "ip" : [
                                                "3.3.3.3",
                                                "4.4.4.4",
                                                "128.2.1.6"
                                        ]
                                }
                        ],
                        "currentFeed" : "test2",
                        "hostName" : "wsd",
                        "password" : "dsas",
                        "ip" : "3.132.76.52"
                }
        ]
}
```

I need to update the document:

```
if(Rid==my_id){
 if(`details.code`==my_code){
   if('details.list.name'==my_name){
     add to the `details.list.ip` array
   }else{
     add in the `details.list` array.
   }
 }else{
  add it in the `details` array.
 }
}else {
 create new document.
}
```

I'm able to update the `details.list.ip` array on the conditions using [position operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) in arrayfilter. But it is not working when I need to update the `details.list` array or `details` array or if nothing is present in collection for that `RId` insert it.

**Update**

For example:

---

if I get the request with a document like:

```
      {
        "RId" : 501,
        "details" : [
                {
                        "code" : "code1",
                        "list" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "first",
                                        "ip" : [
                                                "192.4.2.3"
                                        ]
                                }
                        ],
                        "currentFeed" : "test1",
                        "hostName" : "xyz",
                        "password" : "yyz",
                        "ip" : "3.132.76.51"
                }
             ]
       }
```

It should update the `details.list.ip` for `details.list.name:"first"`.

As `RId` matched, `details.code` matched, and `details.list.name` is matched too.

---

Or if I get a request like:

```
     {
        "RId" : 501,
        "details" : [
                {
                        "code" : "code1",
                        "list" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "sixth",
                                        "ip" : [
                                                "192.16.3.2"
                                        ]
                                }
                        ],
                        "currentFeed" : "test1",
                        "hostName" : "xyz",
                        "password" : "yyz",
                        "ip" : "3.132.76.51"
                }
             ]
           }
```

It should update the `details.list` array with the information of code2

As the `RId` matched, `details.code` matched, but `details.list.name` not matched.

---

Or if I get a request like:

```
     {
        "RId" : 501,
        "details" : [
                {
                        "code" : "code3",
                        "list" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "fourth",
                                        "ip" : [
                                                "192.168.3.2"
                                        ]
                                }
                        ],
                        "currentFeed" : "test1",
                        "hostName" : "xyz",
                        "password" : "yyz",
                        "ip" : "3.132.76.51"
                }
             ]
           }
```

It should update the `details` array with the information of code3

As `RId` matched, but `details.code` is not matched.

---

Or if the request gets the document:

```
      {
        "RId" : 500,
        "details" : [
                {
                        "code" : "code5",
                        "list" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "fifth",
                                        "ip" : [
                                                "128.2.1.4"
                                        ]
                                }
                        ],
                        "currentFeed" : "test1",
                        "hostName" : "xyz",
                        "password" : "yyz",
                        "ip" : "3.132.76.51"
                }
             ]
           }
```

It should create a new document as `RId:500` is not present in the collection.

As `Rid` not matched

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: what is your input & required o/p ? So just wanted to add a new element in `ip` array or `details` array or `list` array something like that ?

Comment: @whoami I have updated the question.